# Multiple Rows in single column

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

i am using POSTGRESQL 9.1.3 as a backend and VS2010 c#  as frontend.
I have two tables as follows :

**Property**

```
Property_id   Property_details
------------------------------
1             abc
2             xyz
```

**Claimers**

```
Claimer_ID  First_name  Last_Name Property_id
---------------------------------------------
1           aaaa        bbbbb       1
2           cccc        ddddd       2
3           eeee        fffff       1
4           gggg        hhhhh       2
```

I want following output

```
Property_id   Claimers
------------------------------------
1             aaa bbbb,eeee ffff
2             ccc dddd,gggg hhhh
3             (may be more than 2 claimers)
```

Here claimer is a single column which may contain 1 or more than 1 (upto 50) claimer names

how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a."Property_id",
        array_agg(b."First_name" || ' ' || b."Last_Name") AS "Claimers"
FROM    Property a
        INNER JOIN Claimers b
            ON a."Property_id" = b."Property_id"
GROUP BY a."Property_id"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e7375/5)
- [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html)